# Spring Boot maven spring-could-starter-parent Brixton.RELEASE changes hibernate-core dependency

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a project that depends on hibernate-core 3.6.4.Final, lets call it "MyDatabaseProject".

I have a second project which is a spring-cloud project, it depends on MyDatabaseProject.

The spring cloud project uses spring-cloud-starter-parent Brixton.RELEASE as it's parent pom.

When I check the dependencies (using "mvn dependency:list") I see that I now have a dependency on hibernate-core:4.3.11.Final, not 3.6.4.Final.

If I switch the spring-cloud-starter-parent version back to Angel.SR6, and I check the dependencies (using "mvn dependency:list") I see that I have a dependency on hibernate-core:3.6.4.Final, as I would expect.

It appears to me that something changed in the Brixton.RELEASE that overrides the hibernate-core version.

**My question is, is this a bug, or unintentional change in the Brixton.RELEASE?**

**If it is intentional, what it the correct way to deal with this?**

I have tried adding a dependencyManagement section to the spring cloud project pom with the hibernate-core:3.6.4.Final, and that did work, but I don't know if that is the correct way to deal with the problem. It doesn't seem right for the top level project to care about what hibernate version the lower level project uses.

Here are the minimal maven poms for the spring cloud project and the database project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySpringCloudProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- <version>Angel.SR6</version> -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>example</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyDatabaseProject</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And the database project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyDatabaseProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: If you use mvn dependency:tree instead you'll see what owns the hib-4 deps.

Comment: Just specify the `hibernate.version` property. Is isn't something in Spring Cloud but in Spring Boot which is actually managing the dependencies. If I recall correctly the structure of the pom's is a bit different now leading to having the `spring-boot-dependencies` included and take precedence.

Comment: @M.Deinum I appreciate the answer and the rough explanation. That's exactly the type of thing I was looking for. If you can add an answer I will accept it.